# running pyspark script on EMR

Tags: python, apache-spark

I currently automate my Apache Spark Pyspark scripts using clusters of EC2s using Sparks preconfigured ./ec2 directory. For automation and scheduling purposes, I would like to use Boto EMR module to send scripts up to the cluster.

I was able to bootstrap and install Spark on a cluster of EMRs. I am also able to launch a script on EMR by using my *local* machine's version of pyspark, and setting master like such:

```
$: MASTER=spark://<insert EMR master node of cluster here> ./bin/pyspark <myscriptname.py>
```

However, this requires me to run that script locally, and thus I am not able to fully leverage Boto's ability to 1) start the cluster 2) add the script steps and 3) stop the cluster. I've found examples using script-runner.sh and emr "step" commands for spark-shell (scala), but I assume there is an easier way to do this with the Python module (pyspark). Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 18):

Here is a [great example](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx578UTQUV7LRP/Submitting-User-Applications-with-spark-submit) of how it needs to be configured. Browse to "A quick example" for Python code.

However, in order to make things working in emr-4.7.2, a few tweaks had to be made, so here is a AWS CLI command that worked for me:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id <Your EMR cluster id> --steps Type=spark,Name=TestJob,Args=[--deploy-mode,cluster,--master,yarn,--conf,spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true,s3a://your-source-bucket/code/pythonjob.py,s3a://your-source-bucket/data/data.csv,s3a://your-destination-bucket/test-output/],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```

And here is a contents of `pythonjob.py` file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark import SparkContext
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: testjob  ", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)
    sc = SparkContext(appName="MyTestJob")
    dataTextAll = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
    dataRDD = dataTextAll.map(lambda x: x.split(",")).map(lambda y: (str(y[0]), float(y[1]))).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
    dataRDD.saveAsTextFile(sys.argv[2])
    sc.stop()
```

It reads the `data.csv` file from S3, splits every row, converts first value to string and a second to float, groups by first value and sums the values in the second column, and writes the result back to S3.

A few comments:

- I've decided to leave `spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=true` so
  that I can monitor job execution in console.
- Input and output paths (`sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` respectively) are passed to the script as part of the job sumbission (`Args` section in `add-steps` command).
- [Be aware](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3) that you must use `s3a://` URI instead of `s3n://` and `s3://` for Hadoop 2.7+ when configuring your job.
- If your cluster is in VPC, you need to create a [VPC Endpoint for Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/) if you intend to read/write from there in your EMR jobs.

Comment: What if you want to run a script within a larger git repository? I can clone the repo into the cluster through a bootstrap action but then how do you `spark-submit --master yarn /path/to/script_to_run.py`?

Comment: @EvanZamir, I guess you can try to use a [command runner](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-commandrunner.html) in that case

Comment: Thanks for the comments and detail, very helpful.

Comment: **@Matt**, **@Dmitry Deryabin** `boto3` docs state that [`add-steps`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/add-steps.html) **require `Jar`**. where does that leave those who want to perform `spark-submit` using a `pyspark` script, and how to pass my `pyspark` script?

Comment: Ok, as rightly suggested by **@Dmitry Deryabin**, `command-runner.jar` is meant for such use-cases; **@Taro Sato** has [explained it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39763973/3679900) well

Answer (score 5):

This might be helpful though it does not use boto.

Use aws cli to create the cluster and add steps(spark job) to it.

1)Create the cluster:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "Spark cluster" --ami-version 3.8 --applications Name=Spark --ec2-attributes KeyName=ir --log-uri s3://Path/logs --instance-type m3.xlarge  --instance-count 1 --use-default-roles
```

2) add step(spark job). Note that your python script should be stored in master node(in this case it is in /home/hadoop/spark ).

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-xxxxxxx --steps Name=Spark,Jar=s3://eu-west-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,Args=[/home/hadoop/spark/bin/spark-submit,--deploy-mode,client,/home/hadoop/spark/myscript.py],ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE
```

you can also combine two steps into one and create cluster/run job and terminate the cluster.

Few notes: 1)I have tried multiple ways to read the script from S3 but no Luck :(

so I ended up copying it using either boto or aws cli to the node. 2) since I was testing that on one node in emr the deploy mode in step is client for client you should change that to cluster.

Answer (score 3):

you need to change the deploy-mode to cluster (instead of client) to access the script from S3.