# Add streaming step to MR job in boto3 running on AWS EMR 5.0

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, emr, boto3

I'm trying to migrate a couple of MR jobs that I have written in python from AWS EMR 2.4 to AWS EMR 5.0. Till now I was using boto 2.4, but it doesn't support EMR 5.0, so I'm trying to shift to boto3. Earlier, while using boto 2.4, I used the `StreamingStep` module to specify input location and output location, as well as the location of my mapper and reducer source files. Using this module, I effectively didn't have to create or upload any jar to run my jobs. However, I cannot find the equivalent for this module anywhere in the boto3 documentation. How can I add a streaming step in boto3 to my MR job, so that I don't have to upload a jar file to run it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's unfortunate that boto3 and EMR API are rather poorly documented. Minimally, the word counting example would look as follows:

```
import boto3

emr = boto3.client('emr')

resp = emr.run_job_flow(
    Name='myjob',
    ReleaseLabel='emr-5.0.0',
    Instances={
        'InstanceGroups': [
            {'Name': 'master',
             'InstanceRole': 'MASTER',
             'InstanceType': 'c1.medium',
             'InstanceCount': 1,
             'Configurations': [
                 {'Classification': 'yarn-site',
                  'Properties': {'yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled': 'false'}}]},
            {'Name': 'core',
             'InstanceRole': 'CORE',
             'InstanceType': 'c1.medium',
             'InstanceCount': 1,
             'Configurations': [
                 {'Classification': 'yarn-site',
                  'Properties': {'yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled': 'false'}}]},
        ]},
    Steps=[
        {'Name': 'My word count example',
         'HadoopJarStep': {
             'Jar': 'command-runner.jar',
             'Args': [
                 'hadoop-streaming',
                 '-files', 's3://mybucket/wordSplitter.py#wordSplitter.py',
                 '-mapper', 'python2.7 wordSplitter.py',
                 '-input', 's3://mybucket/input/',
                 '-output', 's3://mybucket/output/',
                 '-reducer', 'aggregate']}
         }
    ],
    JobFlowRole='EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
    ServiceRole='EMR_DefaultRole',
)
```

I don't remember needing to do this with boto, but I have had issues running the simple streaming job properly without disabling `vmem-check-enabled`.

Also, if your script is located somewhere on S3, download it using `-files` (appending `#filename` to the argument make the downloaded file available as `filename` in the cluster).

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. It worked. Unfortunately the bounty I set for this ended a couple of hours before you answered it. But thanks a ton anyways. :)